# Can I load data with jQuery without the browser showing that things are loading?

Tags: jquery, background, loading

When my site first loads, there's an array being filled with information from a database that I'm grabbing with jQuery (from google fusion tables). There's a lot of info, so it takes a good 3 - 10 seconds based on how things are going. It's not needed right away, and the rest of the page loads up. My issue is that the browser icon is still spinning and the mouse is spinning (hourglass, whatever). Makes sense, things are still loading, but I don't want the user to feel like they're still waiting when they're actually good to go. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Kenny, I usually create a div semitransparent overlay and change a label on that from callbacks as each event completes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split your process function to 2 parts: 1) the main process (long queries...)  and 2) ajax function to check that main process's result. (you can store the result in file, db or memcache...)

Then it only takes a few ms to go back to the server to check for the result. Users won't see loading cursor anymore.